# Array callback for every item apart from one

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jwplayer

I have the following array:

```
var videos = [];

$('.video').each(function(){
    videos.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

and inside here:

```
events: {
    onPlay: function() {
        var id = vid.attr('id');
        var index = videos.indexOf(id);
        videos.splice(index, 1);
        console.log(videos);
    }
}
```

I have also tried something like this:

```
// if($(this).attr('id') != $('.video').attr('id') ){
//  jwplayer( $('.video').attr('id')).stop();
// }
```

I want to run a function for every array item (videos) apart from the array value equal to:

```
vid.attr('id')
```

I am using splice but that removes the item completely and since I have multiple videos I will end up with an empty array. I basically want only one video to play at the time so I need to stop the others.

Full function code:

```
$(function(){
    //add attributes to your ".video" DIV placeholder to customimize output
    //example: data-autostart="true" - see customSettings Object below.
    if (typeof(jwplayer) !== 'undefined'){

        var videos = [];

        $('.video').each(function(){
            videos.push($(this).attr('id'));
        });

        $('.video').each(function(){
            var vid = $(this),
            videoSettings = {},
            settings = {
                autostart: false,
                width: '100%',
                aspectratio: '16:9',
                image: ''
            },
            customSettings = {
                autostart: vid.attr('data-autostart'),
                width: vid.attr('data-width'),
                aspectratio: vid.attr('data-aspectratio'),
                image: vid.attr('data-image')
            };
            $.extend(videoSettings, settings, customSettings);

            var playerInstance = jwplayer( vid.attr('id') ).setup({
                primary: "flash",
                file: Drupal.settings.basePath + $(this).attr('data-src'),
                autostart: videoSettings.autostart,
                aspectratio: videoSettings.aspectratio,
                image: Drupal.settings.basePath + videoSettings.image,
                skin: "glow",
                stretching: "exactfit",
                width: videoSettings.width,
                events: {
                    onPlay: function() {
                        var id = vid.attr('id');
                        var index = videos.indexOf(id);
                        videos.splice(index, 1);
                        console.log(videos);
                     // if($(this).attr('id') != $('.video').attr('id') ){
                     //    jwplayer( $('.video').attr('id')).stop();
                     // }
                    }
                }
                // ga:{idstring: videoSettings.videotitle,
                //     trackingobject: "pageTracker"
                // }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a simple forEach?

```
onPlay: function() {
    var id = vid.attr('id');
    videos.forEach(function(videoId) { 
       if(videoId != id) {
           //You may want to check first if video is running at all
           jwplayer(videoId).stop();
       }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
onPlay: function() {
    var id = vid.attr('id');

    for (var v in videos) {
        if(id != v[i]) {
            jwplayer(v[i].stop();
        }
    }
}
```